# Debian 8 Jessie - Docker can't run Image

Tags: debian, docker, debian-jessie

I have a problem on my server with a Docker. When I want to run a example image hello-world. I receive an error from console.

```
root@physsrv1:~# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: could not create session key: too many links.
```

Where is the problem?

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:40:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:40:59 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Server:

```
root@physsrv1:~# uname -a
Linux physsrv1 3.16.6-042stab116.2 #1 SMP Fri Jun 24 15:33:57 MSK 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks for help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MSK` in your uname output makes me assume you are running in an OpenVZ virtual machine. If so, check [this link](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/24131).

In short, the underlying OpenVZ host might not be running a recent enough kernel; 2.6.x instead of 3.10+, this will not work with Docker.

Updating the host kernel is the only way to fix this with this version of docker.
OP mentions downgrading docker version also fixes this.

Comment: Thank you, I used command:

apt-get install docker-engine=1.10.3-0~jessie

to install older version of Docker. It works. :)